# LibCurl - Release Static Lib linking problems

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, curl, libcurl

I have been at this for some time now. I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

These are the steps I have taken so far:

-Downloaded the latest version of cURL (7.21.7).

-Opened the solution in Visual Studio 2010 using the vc6curl.dsw and converted the projects to VS2010.

-Set the libcurl project configuration to "release" and built. Build succeeded.A folder called "LIB-Release" is created. It contains several obj files and the "libcurl.lib" file resides here as well.

Test Application:

-In the project's settings I pointed the compiler to the curl includes (headers).

C/C++ >> General >> Additional Include Directories

-Added "CURL_STATICLIB" to the preprocessor definitions

C/C++ >> Preprocessor Definitions

-Added the path to the "libcurl.lib" folder in my linker additional library dependencies

Link >> General >> Additional Library Directories

-Added "libcurl.lib" to my linker additional dependencies

Link >> Input >> Additional Dependencies

-Set my projects configuration to "Realease" and hit build!

I get 42 unresolved externals errors:

> Error 65  error LNK1120: 42 unresolved
>   externals C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\curl_static_lib\Release\curl_static_lib.exe curl_static_lib
>   Error 61  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   ___WSAFDIsSet@8   C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\curl_static_lib\curl_static_lib\libcurl.lib(select.obj) curl_static_lib
>   Error 59  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_accept@12  C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\curl_static_lib\curl_static_lib\libcurl.lib(ftp.obj)    curl_static_lib
>   Error 46  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_ber_free   C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\curl_static_lib\curl_static_lib\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)   curl_static_lib
>   Error 26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_bind@12    C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\curl_static_lib\curl_static_lib\libcurl.lib(connect.obj)    curl_static_lib

I have tried building using the "Debug" configuration as well. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You might try to build with NMAKE using Makefile.vc from ./winbuild folder, or using Makefile.vc8(9,10) from ./lib folder. Just run "nmake -f <Makefile>" from VS command prompt.

Comment: Man! I have tried using the make file many times but I didn't notice there is a switch for version 10 of the makefile

Comment: If you want to add your answer Ill check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to build CURL for windows is to use NMake with provided Makefiles. 
You can

1. Modify Makefile in root folder of CURL to set VC version you use and then run `nmake vc-all` (or choose any other VC target suitable for you). Check "Win32" section of ./docs/INSTALL file.
2. Use Makefile.vc from ./winbuild folder. Check ./winbuild/BUILD.WINDOWS.txt on how to use it.

Comment: This worked. The command I added the optional argument vc=10 to nmake. This built a static libcurl_a.lib

Answer (score 0):

These errors mean that there are functions that libcurl uses that are not in any of the import libraries specified in your linker config.

Sounds like at least the sockets import lib (ws2_32.lib) should be there.

Note that if you compile libcurl as a DLL then all the import libraries are specified as part of the linking of the DLL, so your application then does not need to import all these libraries and just needs to link against the curl import lib. The fact that you chose to compile curl as a static lib makes the curl code part of your application so all the support libs must be provided in your app's linker config.

Comment: Should this lib have been created with the libcurl build or are you suggesting that I need to import other libraries?

Comment: You need to import other libraries from the system, at least ws2_32.lib, maybe others, depending on what symbols are missing. What I typically do when I get undefined symbols is to locate them in msdn. The documentation generally states what lib a symbol belongs to, so it is just a matter of finding all the dependencies that curl needs.